# Adding WHERE YEAR breaks calculation

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very simple query:

```
SELECT a, b, a+b as c FROM records
```

Which works just great. He is an example from the results:

```
Array ( [a] => 100.92 [b] => 21.00 [c] => 121.92 )
```

But the minute I try to filter the records by year:

```
SELECT a, b, a+b as c FROM records
WHERE YEAR(`mydate`) = '2011'
```

The a+b calculation disappears:

```
Array ( [a] => 100.92 [b] => 21.00 [c] => )
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Updates:

1. I've been asked for the actual SQL, here it is:

   SELECT credit, debit, credit+debit as total FROM transactions
   WHERE YEAR(`transaction_date`) = '2011'
2. The transaction_date is a **DATE** field-type.
3. Also, either the credit or debit field is always zero.
4. PHP Code:

**Code**

```
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/pool/_/db.php");

$sql = "SELECT credit, debit, credit+debit as total FROM transactions
            WHERE YEAR(`transaction_date`) = 2011";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Silly question, but what is the datatype of `mydate`? You should avoid using functions around columns in your `WHERE` clause. `WHERE mydate LIKE '2011-%'` is much better.

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters but the Year function will return an integer value.

Comment: @njk Just tried the LIKE, same problem. Also happens when I do it like this: mydate > '2012-01-01'.

Comment: @Whit You don't need the single quotes around `2011`. The function returns an integer.

Comment: Show us _the code_ where this query is made. The problem is not the query.

Comment: @njk Gotcha. But even without them, it still has the same issue.

Comment: The query would return no result if the condition failed. I'm not sure why you're searching for a problem when the query clearly works due to a returning resultset.

Comment: @Whit Can you do us a favor and make a SQL Fiddle using a sample of your schema and data?

Comment: @VincentSavard The query seems to be returning a zero number for a non-zero calculated value. I am not searching for a problem, I am searching for a cause.

Comment: Whit, there is two choices: either your PHP script messes with your array, or the calculation returns null. Since you proved your query does not return null when there is no condition, it is easy to assume the problem lies in your PHP script.

Comment: @njk Hell, it works perfectly in the Fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce45e/1

Comment: @Whit Time to move into debugging your PHP script.

Comment: The only thing I can think is that either `credit` or `debit` is `NULL` (not `0`) which, in turn, would make the value of `total` `NULL` as well.  Try this and see if it changes anything `... COALESCE(credit, 0) + COALESCE(debit, 0) as total ...`

Comment: @SeanBright, go ahead and add that as an answer, so I can upvote it and accept it. Thank you sir.

Comment: Well.  I think that was fun for everybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think is that either `credit` or `debit` is `NULL` (not `0`) which, in turn, would make the value of total `NULL` as well. Try this and see if it changes anything:

```
... COALESCE(credit, 0) + COALESCE(debit, 0) as total ...
```